# Is session cookie with session_start() automatically available under Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception

what do I have to do to make the `PHPSESSID` cookie testable?

I have index.php where I set the cookie with `session_start ()`, which gets me in "real life" the session cookie "`PHPSESSID`".

Now I just want to see that the cookie exists with

```
$I->amOnPage('/index.php');
$I->seeCookie('PHPSESSID');
```

but I get

```
Fail Failed asserting that an array contains 'PHPSESSID'.
```

Simple tests like see('something', 'h4') work just fine.

acceptance.suite.yml

```
 actor: AcceptanceTester
 modules:
     enabled:
         - WebDriver:
             url: http://nginx-web/     
             browser: chrome
             host: chrome                
             window_size: maximize
         - \Helper\Acceptance
```

I do run this in Docker with the below images, but that should not make any difference:

```
codeception/codeception:2.3.5 and 
selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.7.1
```

**Question**: Do I have to do something else for the cookie to "come alive"? I am almost thinking I need to use `setCookie` in Codeception, but that does not seem logical (to manually create the cookie). If I did that, I could actually not test if session_start() works.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It does have to do with the docker setup .... and other. Our nginx server is running behind a reverse proxy, plus we have checks, if you do not come from our domain, you are not allowed to perform specific actions. For some, not yet known reason, this also somehow interferes with the cookie, even right from the beginning.

Solution:
in your docker-compose set for the selenium image `extra_hosts`